# Better way of formatting arrays from javascript to php and vice versa?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I am creating a page that will read, write, and modify data in a mysql database.  I am using php with codeigniter to perform the queries however the page that the user will see I am powering with javascript, dynamically filling and changing the data based on the user selections.  To do this I am passing lots of data back and forth from php to javascript functions and vice versa, but I am wondering if there is a better way of formatting the data.  For example here is a javascript function that uses XMLHttpRequest to call a php function and get the result:

```
var myarray = new Array(2);
myarray[0] = document.getElementById("my_input").value;
myarray[1] = document.getElementById("my_select").value;
xmlhttp.open("POST", "my_url/my_function/"+myarray.join('|'), false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("my_element").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I simply do an explode() on the string passed to the php function and execute the necessary queries.  This seems like a very awkward interaction between php and javascript.  Is there a better, or at least different, way to do this?

Comment: why not using json?

Comment: Specifically using the `json_encode` and `json_decode` methods detailed here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: And its Javascript counter-part: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: yes, and [JSON.parse and JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSON** (JavaScript Object Notation) seems to be what you are looking for. You can turn pretty much all kind of Javascript variables into a string using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and later recover the original structure in php using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), and viceversa using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

See:

- [PHP documentation on JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)
- [MDN Javascript documentation on JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Is this not basically what I am emulating using the javascript .join() and php explode() functions except that it could be used with a datatype that is not a string?

Comment: @WillSampson technically yes, but it can handle nested arrays or objects for instance, or named properties, scenarios where your method could break. Plus, json is a pretty common standard used almost everywhere nowadays.

Comment: Bear in mind JSON.stringify is not natively supported in IE 7 or 6, so you will need to use a parser like json2 is you wish to support them.